# Optimizing SQL Server view

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to optimize a big query that contains about 10 subqueries on a table with 30+ columns and over 2 million records.

I would like to reduce the amount of selects on this massive table but I don't really know how I could optimize following query to prevent this.

I would like to use some kind of filter on a so that I can just write down a WHERE clause in the column subquery instead of querying tableA again, but I have no clue on how I could do this:

```
SELECT 
    col1, col2,
    (SELECT COUNT(col3) 
     FROM tableA ta
     INNER JOIN tableB b ON tl.TaskId = b.col6
     INNER JOIN tableC c ON b.Id = c.TaskId
     WHERE c.ResultCode = 1 
       AND ta.col4 = a.col4 
       AND ta.col5 = a.col5) as Executed,
   (SELECT COUNT(col3) 
    FROM tableA ta
    INNER JOIN tableB b ON tl.TaskId = b.col6
    INNER JOIN tableC c ON b.Id = c.TaskId
    WHERE c.ResultCode = 9 
      AND ta.col4 = a.col4 
      AND ta.col5 = a.col5) as NotExecuted
FROM 
   tableA a
GROUP BY 
   col1, col2, col4, col5
```

Comment: You should be able to fix this conditional aggregation.  However, without sample data and desired results, it is quite difficult to specify the exact query.

Comment: what is tl alias? INNER JOIN tableB b ON tl.TaskId = b.col6. And col3, what table it's belong to?

Answer (score 0):

I have few questions about your query (asked in comment), however it is might what you are looking for:

```
SELECT
    col1 ,
    col2 ,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN c.ResultCode = 1 THEN 1
               ELSE NULL
          END) AS Executed ,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN c.ResultCode = 9 THEN 1
               ELSE NULL
          END) AS NotExecuted
FROM
    tableA a
    JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.tableA_id
    JOIN tableC c ON a.id = c.tableB_id
WHERE
    c.ResultCode IN ( 1, 9 )
GROUP BY
    col1 ,
    col2;
```

If you do not need it in separate columns, then you can aggregate it in separate rows. That would probably work faster:

```
SELECT
    col1 ,
    col2 ,
    CASE c.ResultCode
      WHEN 1 THEN 'Executed'
      WHEN 9 THEN 'Not Executed'
    END,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    tableA a
    JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.tableA_id
    JOIN tableC c ON a.id = c.tableB_id
WHERE
    c.ResultCode IN ( 1, 9 )
GROUP BY
    col1 ,
    col2 ,
    c.ResultCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  col1, col2, sum(case when c.ResultCode = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Executed,
  sum(case when c.ResultCode = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NotExecuted
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.TaskId = b.col6
INNER JOIN tableC c ON b.Id = c.TaskId
GROUP BY   col1, col2
```